# Adding a screen before GameScene.swift in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in XCode using Swift and I want to add a starting screen before the actual game. I don't want just an image that fades out, I want a screen with "play", "select character", and some buttons. I don't know if i should add a new swift file, add a sks file, edit the GameScene.swift file? I'm just starting to develop in SpriteKit and it would be great if you could explain me how to do this properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Follow this Step by step and it should work:

1. Open up your Interface Builder (main.storyboard) and add a `UIViewController`.
2. Select the new `UIViewController`, go to Editor > Embed In > UINavigationController

   2. a. To remove the UINavBar for your game scene you'll be able to do this using the *property* `navigationBarHidden` in the Game Scene View Controller
3. Add the UIButtons and/or other controls of your choice to your new View Controller
4. Left Click (ctrl) and drag the **PLAY** UIControl to the View Controller displaying your Game Scene.
5. Connect the other UIControls after adding other View Controllers that are associated with their UIControl counterpart. **(see below)**

#### If you've only ever programmed using the SpriteKit Template file, I would recommend looking over this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html)

~ *MORE Details* ~

Having successfully added your **Start Screen**, or your Root View Controller, add one ViewController for each page, or screen, that you'll need the Start Screen to display, by dragging one at a time into the Storyboard file.

Having all the Screens you'll need represented by the View Controllers within your main.storyboard file, the next step is **Control Clicking** from each UIButton on your "Start Screen" to the ViewController that will display its target screen.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand the 4 and 5. Take into account that I don't work with the views like that, I'm only working in code and in the .swift and .sks files.

Comment: Your best chance at reaching your desired goals, having only worked with SpriteKit and not Interface Builder, would be to familiarize yourself with the link at the bottom.

Comment: I know that like the palm of my hand, I've already made 3 apps. But I'm working in this game based on a tutorial to learn, and I don't want to change everything. Plus, how do I "connect" the View to the .swift file?

Comment: I apologize for over simplifying a segue by using the term ***connect***, but if you're familiar with the concept you should be able to present the GameSceneViewController from the Starting Screen you're wanting.

Comment: You're just adding a Home Page with options, that will present the GameSceneViewController and the other Views and/or View Controllers that you're in need of.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create new sprite kit scene and new swift file,
then put class of your swift file into Custom Class inspector in the 
gamescene.sks so it will work just like default GameScene.

[image: g]

then initialise your menu scene in viewDidLoad instead of original GameScene

```
if let menu = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenu") {
  menu.scaleMode = .aspectFill
  view.presentScene(menu)
}
```

You can switch to your original scene like this(for example):

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let posistion = touch.location(in: self)
        let node = self.atPoint(posistion)
        if node == yourNode {
            if let originalScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                originalScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                view?.presentScene(originalScene)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, it was just not direct answer so I had to edit it.